# Can there be a coordinate system on plane without dedicated directions or points?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Can there be a coordinate system on plane without dedicated directions (as in Cartesian) or points (as in polar system)? If no, why?

Comment: As long as the coordinate *values* (e.g., real numbers) have special values (such as $0$), this seems hard to accomplish ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen in Cartesian system zero is not a special point. But it has two dedicated directions.

Comment: Depends on what you consider a co-ordinate system to be.